# Difference between components in material-ui lab @material-ui/lab/ and material-ui core

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This might seem like a generic question , I really liked the scalability of material ui when compared to couple of other react open source frameworks..

**Question** Whats the difference between components in "@material-ui/core and "@material-ui/lab?
The material ui documentation says "This lab hosts the incubator components that are not yet ready to move to the core." So when it says the components are not ready to move to core, what does that mean? (Im looking for something a bit more deterministic like the component has not been completely tested/waiting for user reviews/ major bugs can be expected etc etc).

For eg WRT code in  the below sandbox ,it uses @material-ui/lab/Autocomplete.
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-multiselect-working-ig9s8 . How can I infer/determine how good it is currently. Didnt see any updates in last few months roadmaps...

Comment: Update : I had used some components in material ui lab and it was ok - Didnt face any unusual build problems or anythin. I guess its like use at your own risk kinda thing

Depends on ur application too I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Material-UI website:

"The main difference between the lab and the core is how the components are versioned. Having a separate lab package allows us to release breaking changes when necessary while the core package follows a slower-moving policy.

As developers use and test the components and report issues, the maintainers learn more about shortcomings of the components: missing features, accessibility issues, bugs, API design, etc. The older and more used a component is, the less likely it is that new issues will be found and subsequently need to introduce breaking changes.

For a component to be ready to move to the core, the following criteria are considered:

- It needs to be used. The Material-UI team uses Google Analytics stats among other metrics to evaluate the usage of each component. A lab component with low usage either means that it isn't fully working yet or that there is a low demand for it.
- It needs to match the code quality of the core components. It doesn't
  have to be perfect to be a part of the core, but the component should
  be reliable enough that developers can depend on it.

  - Each component needs type definitions. It is not currently required that a lab component is typed, but it would need to be typed to move to the core.
  - Requires good test coverage. Some of the lab components don't
    currently have comprehensive tests.
- Can it be used as leverage to incentivize users to upgrade to the latest major release? The less fragmented the community is, the better.
- It needs to have a low probability of a breaking change in the
  short/medium future. For instance, if it needs a new feature that
  will likely require a breaking change, it may be preferable to delay
  its promotion to the core."

https://material-ui.com/components/about-the-lab/

**Summary**
So as I understood it, lab components may not be tested, typed or aren't widely used. In addition, they might have poor code quality or are pending features/refactors that might radically change the API.

Comment: Accepting this answer . Side Note :I did ask around peers and they gave a similar answer and I did implement a feature from lab  (for a sparsely used app). Seemed ok

Comment: Yeh, I'm sure they work for the most part right away, but later on a lab component could get it's API or functionality changed. So probably from a developer perspective updating your apps dependencies later on might require some(or a lot) of extra work with Lab components, compared to core components. Not sure if the component could be removed from Lab also, if not enough of people are using it.